# Number of expected pairs in a random shuffle

Tags: expected-value

Suppose there are 34 poeople standing in a row in random order, among them 18 are male and 16 are female. If two people adjacent to each other belong to different genders, we consider them to be a couple, how many couples are we expected to see on average?

Comment: Is MFM one couple and one person left over, or two couples (one F having two Ms)?

Comment: They are considered two couples.

Comment: Good. That's probably easier, because now your problem is equivalent to the number of *changes* in a random sequence of 18 Ms and 16 Fs.

Comment: Employ indicator random variables.  One candidate would be the indicator of the gender of the person behind a female, for instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, we find the probability that two adjacent individuals are of different genders.  Those two people are equally likely to be   any of the ${34 \choose 2}$ pairs of people, of which $18 \times 16$ are male-female pairs, so this probability is $(18 \times 16)/{34 \choose 2}$.

The total number of pairs is $X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{33}$ where $X_i$ is an indicator random variable that is 1 if person $i$ and person $i+1$ are of opposite genders and 0 otherwise.  Its expectation is $E(X_1) + \cdots + E(X_{33})$, but all these variables have the same expectation, the probability we found above. So the answer is

$$ 33 \times {18 \times 16 \over {34 \choose 2}} = {33 \times 18 \times 16 \over (34 \times 33)/2} = {18 \times 16 \over 17} = {17^2 - 1 \over 17}  = 17 - {1 \over 17} \approx 16.94.$$

This agrees with Bernhard's simulation.

More generally, if you have $m$ males and $f$ females and the same problem you get

$$ (m+f-1) {mf \over {m+f \choose 2}} = {(m+f-1) mf \over (m+f)(m+f-1)/2} = {2mf \over m+f}$$

which can  also be checked by simulation.

Comment: Amazing derivation. How did you avoid getting trapped into thinking about drawing random samples without replacement?

Comment: Lots of practice.  Seriously, though, if you're only looking for the expected value then using indicator random variables is usually the way to go.  (You can derive the variance this way as well but it's more work - you end up having to consider two indicators at a time.)

Comment: This is a really nice solution. I **did not** expect the answer to be the *harmonic mean* of $m$ and $f$, but there it is!

Comment: Even more generally, one should look for any excuse to use linearity of expectation—which means that writing a random variable as a complicated sum of simple random variables is usually a productive way to find the expectation.

Comment: Would you mind if I include a link to this answer in the hint for https://github.com/atorch/probability_puzzles/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml#L651 ?

Comment: @Adrian - go ahead! Sadly I can't actually see the app as an iOS user, but from what I  can see at the link it looks like a nice bunch of puzzles!

Answer (score 5):

Someone much wiser then me will post a theoretical and exact solution. Meanwhile my attempt at a simulation:

```
once <- function(){
    row <- sample(c(rep("m", 18), rep("f",16)))
    count <- 0
    for(i in 1:33){
        if(row[i]!=row[i+1]) 
        count <- count + 1
    }
    return(count)
}


run <- replicate(1e5, once())
plot(table(run))
```

[image]

```
> table(run)
run
    6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29 
    5    25    79   280   663  1643  3070  5555  8057 11169 12883 14309 12818 11020  7682  5279  2931  1535   635   261    78    17     4     2

> summary(run)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   6.00   15.00   17.00   16.96   19.00   29.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the simulation. Unfortunately this is a job interview question. If I could run simulations many problems could be in solved very easily.

Comment: @XiaowenLi: If you have a job interview definitely outline a simulation approach too. (And I hope it goes well of course!)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution :

Imagine the 34 people form a circle instead of a row.
Then for any given female A :

E( # couples A is in) =

E( # righthand couples A is in) + E( # lefthand couples A is in) =

P(to A's right is a man) + P(to A's left is a man) =
m/(m+f-1) + m/(m+f-1) =  2m/(m+f-1)

So E( total # of couples) = f * E( # couples A is in) = **2mf/(m+f-1)**

This is the expectation when the people form a circle. To form a row the circle is cut in a random place. The  number of potential couples decreases from (m+f) to (m+f-1), i.e. with a factor (m+f-1)/(m+f) and the expected number of couples decreases proportionally:

(2mf/(m+f-1)) * (m+f-1)/(m+f) = **2mf/(m+f)**